# Why are there unreachable bananas?

Tags: despicable-me-minion-rush

Right when you start running on Minion beach (before you jump on the spring), look on the the top left corners of the screen. There are floating bananas! I don't know if this is a glitch of there is a special method though. If possible, how do you get them?

**Note:** I play on PC, not mobile. Just to see if it's only PC that has those bananas.

Comment: Can you give us a screenshot of them? That way it'll be easier to tell.

Comment: As an FYI they happen on mobile too. :(

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is a significant glitch in Minion Rush, and it has been spotted not only in the Minion Beach, but in other maps too. If you encounter these during the middle of the map, then, attracted by it, you will crash into a nearby object. So, when you see a banana floating where it shouldn't be, stay away from it.